# Salary Components in Bahrain

Tags: bahrain

I have recently been offered with 1 of the company in bahrain with monthly ctc 0f 994 BHD

when is spoke to HR , he said only basic + HRA+ Other allow will be paid to you on monthly basis which is 600 and rest components like Telephone , transport ,Depended RP cost etc will be not part of my monthly salary .

My concern was if this components are added in my CTC then why i would not be getting this amount on monthly basis

Comment: That is a question you should ask them - there's no way we can know why.